# Filter email being sent by specific user

Tags: linux, email

I have a complicated situation requiring me to set up an outgoing mail filter for one particular mail user.  For security reasons we have become concerned that this user might send confidential information from their mail account.  I have been asked to see if I can set up a filter on outgoing mail for just that user that would allow me to block mail to a certain domain.  Ideally I would like the email to be redirected to an admin user.

My server is a Plesk 10.1.1 server running qmail.  Is there any way to achieve this using the qmail-scanner package?  I have full root access to the server machine.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plesk uses it's own 'version' of QMail so things might get a bit tricky. 
Still there are a couple of things you can try:

Since you have qmail-scanner you can use the --archive option that accepts regex as input so that you archive only email from a particular user
Read qmail scanner documentation [here](http://qmail-scanner.sourceforge.net/configure-options.php).

Plesk used to distribute their particular version of qmail as source along with the directions of how to compile and apply patches. If you can get your hands on that you can use the [qtap](http://www.inter7.com/index.php?page=qmailtap) package from Inter7 that was specifically designed for what you have in mind

In the question of blocking a particular user sending to a particular domain I am not so sure it is possible in a clean manner.
Again there is a [package](http://www.inter7.com/index.php?page=empf) from Inter7 that sort of does what you want.
You can also check if the qmailqueue patch has been applied to Plesk's particular version of Qmail. If it has then you can call a custom script that checks the email headers before sending the email over to qmail-inject for further processing.

Imho if you suspect foul play from an employee talk to a lawyer and he will give you advice. I am not certain that blocking outgoing email to a particular domain will work, since it will be easily picked up and he will just change domains he is sending emails to. Just my 2 cents.